# Validate expiration date automatically

Tags: datetime, odoo, odoo-12

I have created a table in Odoo, where I set the date and time of beginning and end of some activities.

What I want to do is that when the end date and time is less than the current date, update a field in the record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @api.onchange() or compute function to update value of field depending up on another field add @api.depends(field_name) , you write your condition inside this function so whenever value of a field changes this function will be triggered.
you can refer this [link for oncahnge and compute function](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html)